# Is it possible to format text with vim

Tags: vim

is it possible to format text with vim like [here](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.txt). If it is possible how to do that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use word wrapping, if that is what you want.

```
:set wm=2
:set textwidth=72
```

To apply these settings to existing text, use the `gq` command. To apply it to all the text, just hit the following sequence:

```
<ESC>
gg
gq
G
```

Or first select a portion of the text followed by `gq`.

Comment: The [`'textwidth'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'tw') setting has precedence over [`'wrapmargin'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'wm'), so there's no point in setting them both.

Answer (score 4):

Vim has `:set textwidth`, `:set formatoptions` and the `gq` command for wrapping paragraphs. Use `:set smartindent` to enable left alignment. of wrapped paragraphs.

`:left` left-aligns text.

`:center` centers it.

`:right` right-aligns it.

Answer (score 0):

You also can use a regex to reshape text width at desired dimensions:

```
:%s/\(.\{68}.\{-}\s\)/\1\r/g
```